# Elimination Matrix Specific entry question

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

Given a $3 \times 3$ array $$
A =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 &1 \\ 3 & 8 & 1 \\ 0 &4 &1 \end{bmatrix},
$$

My understanding is that that I subtract $3$ times row one from row two to eliminate entry $a_{21}$. Therefore $E_{21}$ should be
$$
E_{21} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \mathbf{0} & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & 4 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
I see in my notes that elimination by **multiplication** yields $$
E_{21} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \mathbf{-3} & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$.

I would like to understand the intuition behind the entries in the multiplication matrix.  I am able to follow how one would find the entries for $E_{21}$ using the subtraction method (I highlighted $0$ to illustrate that I understand where that comes from, but I am supposed to use the multiplication method and I do not understand how one reaches these entries. Specifically the highlighted $-3$.  Can someone please explain to me how to use the multiplication method to eliminate entries in a matrix?

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, you may find [this article](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/ax-b-and-the-four-subspaces/elimination-with-matrices/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses1.2sum.pdf) helpful. Would you mind explaining what  a "multiplication matrix" is, and what the "subtraction" and "multiplications" methods to which you refer are? Is each $E_{ij}$ supposed to be an elimination matrix, or a row-equivalent matrix produced at some point during elimination? Your work seems to suggest the latter, while your notes suggest the former (both with some errors).

Comment: You will also note that this very example appear in the article I linked in my previous comment.

Comment: Of course, I meant to say that I am looking to find the left operand multiplied by original Matrix A that is equal to the elimination matrix E(2,1).  And then, I am to eliminate entry (3,2)--which should be a "4" in my elimination matrix (2,1).  I am struggling with this second step of elimination by matrix multiplication where one needs to fill in the entries for that left hand operand when setting the systems equal to the elimination matrix